# writing a gauge widget using 2 images in qt

Tags: qt, paintevent

I'm writing a gauge widget, using QT, that is constructed from 2 separate images, one as background and the other as Needle. I reimplement paintEvent function as follow:

```
void myGaugeWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPixmap bkgImage(bkgImgPath);
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, width(), height(), bkgImage);

    const double thetaDeg = 30.0;
    QPixmap needle(needles[i].imgPath);
    int needleWidth = 200;
    int needleHeight = 200;

    int anchorX = 20;
    int anchorY = 30;
    const int centerX = width()/2;
    const int centerY = height()/2;

    QTransform rm =  QTransform().translate(-anchorX,- anchorY).rotate(thetaDeg).translate(centerX,centerY);
    needle = needle.transformed(rm);
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0, needle);
}
```

this code rotates my needle correctly but its position is not correct. 
can anybody help me?
thanks.

Comment: You can provide the 2 images to see what the problem is, also show an image of the problem you get.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely would depend on your images and widget size. I have tried your code and it seems to me that `QTransform().translate()` is not doing anything in a `QPixmap`. I tried to give extreme values for `translate()` and removed `rotate()` - the image does not move.

I already have have my own implementation for a gauge. This is with painter transformation instead of the image. My images are of dimensions:

> Gauge Background: 252x252 (there is some external blurring effects around the circle boundaries, making the background image larger than it seems)
>
> Needle: 7x72 ( the image dimensions wrap around the boundaries of the needle itself)
>
> Needle roation center (with respect to the background):  126, 126 (divide background size by 2)
>
> The needle image points upward

For this setup, here is my `paintEvent()` with some explanations:

```
void myGaugeWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    
    //draw the background which is same size as the widget. 
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, bg.width(), bg.height(), bg);
    
    //Calculate the angle of rotation. 
    //The gauge I am using has a cutout angle of 120 degrees at the bottom (symmetric)
    float needleAngle = -120/*offset for start rotation*/ + ((value-minValue)*240/*total sweep of the gauge*//(maxValue-minValue));
    painter.save();

    //translate the painter to the roation center and then perform the rotation
    painter.translate(126, 126);
    painter.rotate(needleAngle);

    //translate the rotated canvas to adjust for the height of the needle. 
    //If you don't do this, your needle's tip will be at the rotation center
    painter.translate(0, -72);

    //draw the needle and adjust for the width with the x value
    painter.drawPixmap(-needle.width()/2, 0, needle.width(), needle.height(), needle);
    painter.restore();
}
```